# Solaris 10: Editing nfs mounts?

Tags: solaris, nfs

I'm working on a Solaris 10 box & I need some help with nfs. My /etc/dfs/sharetab is currently:

```
/myvol   -       nfs     sec=sys,rw=server1:server2
```

How do I add a server3 to the list of where myvol can be mounted? If I'm getting this, sharetab is auto-generated from the contents of /etc/dfs/dfstab but that file has only comment lines on my machine, no share lines ... so how did info about myvol etc show up in sharetab? Maybe I'm not getting this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/myvol` is a ZFS filesystem, it may be shared via the `sharenfs` property. Use `zfs list` to determine the dataset name, then `zfs get sharenfs mypool/myfs` to query the property.

If this is the case, then you can modify it with:

```
zfs set sharenfs="sec=sys,rw=server1:server2:server3" mypool/myfs
```

Answer (score 4):

The line you are seeing in your sharetab would be generated by any valid `share` command. Normally these would be in `/etc/dfs/dfstab` and each line should contain a share command e.g.

```
share -F nfs -o sec=sys,rw=server1:server2:server3 -d "My Volume" /path/to/myvol
```

Check the /etc/rc files and directories/scripts to see if one of them is running a share command.

Check the man pages for dfstab, share and share_nfs.